# How to make a button load HTML into a DIV with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
<!--button gets clicked with ID="Import_audit" -->
$('#import_audit').click(function() {
  $.post("edit_audits.php?action=import", function(data) {
    //need HTML to go into DIV with id = "import_audit_table"
    $('#import_audit_table').html(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<!--JQuery -->
<script src="../bootstrap/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--button-->
<input type="button" value="Transfer Audit" id="import_audit" /> <!--div-->
<DIV id="import_audit_table"></DIV>
```

How can I make it so that when I click a button Jquery can load HTML into a DIV?

Comment: Your last JS line should read `});});` - I'll update your question in an iffy ;)

Comment: Thanks.  I had forgot to add that.  It is updated.  I was migrating from JQuery UI, so wasn't sure the best way to do this?

Comment: @SDJ You need 1 bracket instead of two. `}});` should be `});`

Comment: If your PHP page is returning valid HTML, it should be sufficient to call `$('#import_audit_table').load("edit_audits.php?action=import")` - please see http://api.jquery.com/load/ for more information. You could also pass your `action=import` parameter as separate parameters to the load() function or add a callback to see when loading is done.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/nnxVOLLZiS  I put it in bootply and am trying to have it load google.com as an example.  Doesn't work yet though.

Comment: You will have a tough time to get stuff from a different domain (if you're testing with google.com for example), as your browser will block Cross-Origin requests by default.

Comment: for line comments in html use `<!-- -->` not `//`

Answer (score 0):

From mpf82, answer works.  I had to put the script on the bottom of the  page:

```
<input type="button" value="Transfer Audit" id="import_audit" />
<DIV id="import_audit_table"></DIV>

<style>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#import_audit').click(function(){
         $('#import_audit_table').load("edit_audits.php?action=import");
    });
});
</style>
```